# Modern fantasy novel with yellow cover about girl who discovers she is a witch

Tags: story-identification, novel, urban-fantasy, witches

It was written by a young, female (possibly Australian, I can’t really remember) author and probably came out somewhere between 2008-2013. It begins with the protagonist going about her day to day life (I think she was being bullied at school) until certain strange events cause her to discover she has magical powers (it might have been water magic?). She meets some sassy flying creature who goes on to become her companion. I think it ended on a cliffhanger but a sequel never came out. The story had lots of humorous moments and didn’t take itself too seriously.

The bright yellow cover also had the silhouette of a girl in a shirt and jeans on it. It looked something like this:

[image: book cover]

Unfortunately, that is all I can remember. Please help if you can!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Good first question, and a nice illustration too. If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I'm not confident in this answer enough to make it official, but Diane Duane's "So You Want to Be a Wizard" fits at least some of this.